# snowpark code rertrieving identical results from handler

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can someone let me know when it is better to use the two snowpark python codes?
They both produce the same correct result, but I'm not sure which of the two versions is best practice

snowpark python one

```
start_pos = 15
end_pos = 100000
x_pos = 100

def move(x_pos, byamount=99):
    global start_pos, end_pos
    x_pos += byamount
    if x_pos < start_pos:
        return start_pos
    elif x_pos > end_pos:
        return end_pos
    return x_pos
# x_pos = move(x_pos, 1)
def main(session:snowpark.Session):
    return move(x_pos,1)
```

snowpark python two

```
start_pos = 15
end_pos = 100000
x_pos = 100

def move(session: snowpark.Session, x_pos, byamount=99):
    global start_pos, end_pos
    x_pos += byamount
    if x_pos < start_pos:
        return start_pos
    elif x_pos > end_pos:
        return end_pos
    return x_pos
# x_pos = move(x_pos, 1)
def main(session:snowpark.Session):
    return move(session, x_pos,1)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: For this particular scenario it makes no difference since you're not touching any data stored in Snowflake. Using Snowpark is better when you're working with data stored inside Snowflake.